# Make width from child DIV larger than parent div with CSS

Tags: css, html, width

is it possible to make the '**width**' from a **child DIV** larger than the 'width' from the parent DIV... (**with css only**)

Please see the following example for more details:

> http://jsfiddle.net/6UFs4/

```
    <div id="main">
  <div id="sidebar">DIV1
        <div id="sidebar_2">DIV1 Sub</div>
  </div>
  <div id="page-wrap">DIV2</div>
</div>

#main
{ 
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
#sidebar    
{
    background-color: Aqua;
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
}

#sidebar_2    
{
    background-color: Lime;
}

#page-wrap  
{
    background-color: Gray;
}
```

The size from **DIV1 Sub** should be 100% from browser window and not limited from parent DIV. I tried using **overflow: visible** but it´s not working...

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there are way to make a child DIV's width wider than the parent DIV using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581034/is-there-are-way-to-make-a-child-divs-width-wider-than-the-parent-div-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:absolute` and `width:100%;` to meet your requirements but you have to be careful about position of your element(x and y axis with respect to page) inorder to show your image at desired location

See the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/6UFs4/2/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by changing its positioning.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NPV3M/)

[image]

```
#sidebar_2    
{
    background-color: Lime;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: I don´t know really why but in my code this is not working... Just on JSFiddle I can see that it is working but not in my code... Is there a problem with IE8?

Comment: I just tested it in IE8 and it works fine. It may have issues if you have a `position` rule on any of its ancestors.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this css to your child div:

```
#sidebar_2 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6UFs4/4/