# how to make textarea width larger than form width?

Tags: css, forms, textarea

I am making a form, and I need the width of the textarea to be larger than the form width, as I want to float some elements above the textarea and left of other input fields. I've tried to set the position of textarea to absolute but it's not working. Here is the css I have, and it's making the text area the same width as the form:

```
form {
width: 210px;
overflow: visible;

}
textarea {
height: 215px;
width:370px!important;
}
```

Comment: It looks [fine](http://jsfiddle.net/y8QDW/).

Comment: Now I am totally confused... I've pasted the rest of the styling and html I am using, and it looks fine...

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this works, but try adding these 3 rules to the textarea:

`position:absolute; left:0; right:0;`

Found this tip here: [Is there are way to make a child DIV's width wider than the parent DIV using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581034/is-there-are-way-to-make-a-child-divs-width-wider-than-the-parent-div-using-css)

Comment: If you read the statement of the problem you will notice she already tried that.

Comment: Yes, I've run into that thread before I posted the question, but It's not working :/

Comment: Your question doesnt really work, right now you have a textarea thats nearly twice the size of your form which has no height. If you create a text area that was a little bigger and a form that had height, you could achieve what you want by placing a div in the form area, and then placing a absolute on the div, you then code that div to be the formating of your entire form area. Thats my only solution.  http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/EQxNm/embedded/result/

Comment: Thanks, but my original code on jsfiddle works, which is confusing, as  forms parent div in my code is wider than the form, what else could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Not an elegant solution, but I used `nth-child` to set the `div` around `textarea` to `position: absolute` and `margin-top` of the `div` below to match the height of textarea div...