# Position child container wider than it's Parent container in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically what I want to do, is exactly the same as this question: [Is there are way to make a child DIV's width wider than the parent DIV using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5581034/2518525)

The only issue is that the Drupal theme I'm using is based off of bootstrap which makes the parent element (`col-sm-12`) have a `position: relative;`.

I could do the whole :

```
#my_div_id {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And remove the `position: relative;` from the Bootstrap css definitions of all of the `col-sm-*` classes, but would that cause any adverse issues?

Comment: You can split it into parts say `.container` wrapper for header, custom wrapper for banner and `.container` wrapper for the rest of the content.

Comment: I thought about that @anpsmn and I would've done that by simply creating a region and all for the theme in Drupal, but I'd like to achieve this via the CSS path.

Comment: I guess removing the `position:relative` of all col-* classes would be a bad idea. I feel its better to have a custom section so that you can style it accordingly.

Comment: I agree with @anpsmn. Changing the the default css of the `col-sm_*` classes is a bad idea. Just split the html to different container sections and customize only the one you need to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, the answer is yes. See [**this bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/zBHcwkibwr)

Without knowing your specific requirements, I simply allowed a row to extend beyond the container width with this CSS:

```
.row.expanded{
    width:120%; 
    margin-left:-10%;
}
```

That makes it wider than the parent, and keeps it centered.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, as it does as intended. I did however go with the separate container options, I just wanted to see if there was an alternative. Thanks.

Comment: how did you find 10%  ?

Comment: @HamidShoja 10% is half of the 20% that I enlarged it--that keeps it centered

Comment: seems in this example you know that, I mean if you has a container , for instance bootstrap container, you want to enlarge it full width. how you can find the margins of container ?