# Nested Div (in ui-view) won't extend to full window width

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am having extreme difficulty trying to make a child div extend to the full width of the window, and not just the width of the parent.

I am using Angularjs with  UI-Router, don't know if that is contributing to the problem.

Here is a screen shot.
I would like the image to stretch to the full width of the window.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is a question specific to using UI-Router in Angular.

I had the following in my index.html

```
<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<div class="container">

<!-- THIS IS WHERE WE WILL INJECT OUR CONTENT  ============================== -->
<div ui-view></div>

</div>
```

The outer container div was restricting the content in the ui-view div from stretching to the full width of the window.

Thus, the problem was solved by removing the container div.

Answer (score 0):

Try `position: absolute` on a child

Comment: When I try `position: absolute;` it messes up the hierarchical flow of divs that come after the child image. It's not letting me post a screen shot, but what happens is an image below it now is shown overlapping the child div.

Comment: There's also this approach: 

`.child-element {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
}`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581034/is-there-are-way-to-make-a-child-divs-width-wider-than-the-parent-div-using-css