# Ionic: stretch image in card to device width

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework. 
I am trying to stretch the image in card to match the device width.

Based on the example [here](http://codepen.io/Mest/pen/oKBIu?editors=110), here is my code so far.

```
<div class="list card">

  <div class="item item-avatar">
    <img id="myImg" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/people">
    <h2>Pretty Hate Machine</h2>
    <p>Nine Inch Nails</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item item-image" id="image-container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports">
  </div>

  <a class="item item-icon-left assertive" href="#">
    <i class="icon ion-music-note"></i>
    Start listening
  </a>

</div>
```

### css

```
.item-image img:first-child {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw !important;
  left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
}
```

[Here](http://codepen.io/vineshhpatel/pen/NGbGKY) is the pen I created to share.

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581034/is-there-are-way-to-make-a-child-divs-width-wider-than-the-parent-div-using-css) I referred on SO.

Any help appreciated !!!

Comment: Do you want your image to overflow the card and be full-browser-width?

Comment: Yes, you got it right.

Comment: like this : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVBVox ???

Comment: Have you tried removing the `card` class from your cards? The answer posted does the job, but it will mess up all the cards in your application. You'll need to narrow down your cards to match the desired collection of cards. besides, I'm not a big fan of `!important`s :)

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I'm also not fan of `!important`s :). I will have that improved in my app. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I added these few lines to your css to get your desired outcome:

Add `my-card` class with the `card` and then,

```
.my-card .item.item-image{
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.my-card.card{
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Basically, made the overflow visible on the card, and adjusted for the card's margins.

[Here](http://codepen.io/vineshhpatel/pen/WQoQzP) is working fork of pen !!!

Comment: Avoid using `!important`. If you cannot post a solution that does not use `!important` (unless you actually need to overwrite a very bad coded theme/plugin/framework/etc.. that uses `!important` itself), consider not answering that particular question. Besides, it's clear from your answer that you never worked with `ionic` framework. Your CSS selectors are way too broad.

Comment: I would agree in that it would be smart to add some sort of specific classes in place of using ionic specific selectors.

Comment: Also, I think !important can be necessary if you are overriding ionic's styles already in place (as I've seen when working with the ionic framework)

Comment: Ahhh sweet :) glad you were able to get it sorted

Comment: @PaulG: from my personal experience, working on medium and large projects: it is always better to use longer and more specific selectors instead of using `!important`. If it must be used, more the reason to really use very specific selectors, so it doesn't apply anywhere else, forcing more `!importants`.