# background disappears when scrolling with a top fixed menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue about a menu which is fixed at the top of page when I am scrolling.

In this page, I am using a child div which is wider than the parent div : I do it from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581034/is-there-are-way-to-make-a-child-divs-width-wider-than-the-parent-div-using-css).

menu is well fixed when scrolling but the problem is that image background (the blue "cloud" at the center) into the child div (the horizontal black bar of 100% width) disappears when I start to scroll down, I mean once the menu appears at the top of page.

I don't know how to circumvent this problem.

If someone could see what's wrong,

Thanks

**UPDATE :**

I tried your solutions but it doesn't seem to work . Maybe my issue is not well understood, that's why I put 2 screenshot illustrating the problem :

At the beginning, I have the following top of page :

[image: starting situation]

When I start to scroll down, I get :

[image: image disappeared]

I would like that "blue cloud" image not to disappear.

Comment: can you share a fiddle?

Comment: after getting sticky header..you can do when class is navbar-fixed `background-color:black;background-image:none` in that

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change below css

```
div.horizontal_column {
  background-image: url("../images_template/header2_bg.jpg");
  border-color: #000000;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 0 0;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 150px;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

only Z-index : 9999

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it works ! Could you tell me please briefly how this "z-index: 9999" prevents the occultation of navbar ? at first sight, I would have thought to put "z-index: 9999" to navbar-fixed instead.

Answer (score 1):

Check the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71ndoe0p/1/)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        //if you hard code, then use console
        //.log to determine when you want the 
        //nav bar to stick.  
        //console.log($(window).scrollTop())
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 115) {
        $('.horizontal_center').addClass('navbar-fixed');
        }
        if ($(window).scrollTop() < 115) {
        $('.horizontal_center').removeClass('navbar-fixed');
        }
        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your response but I don't want that horizontal_column to be fixed, I just want only the "<div id="nav_bar" class=""> to be fixed at the top when scrolling down. The background image that disappears when I start to scroll is "background-image: url("../images_template/header_bg.jpg")" into <div class="horizontal_center"> container

Comment: Sorry for the delay, you can test my problem on https://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/71ndoe0p/

Comment: @user1773603 is it not already working? header is sticking to the top when you scroll down on my browser here

Comment: yes but when you begin to scroll down, the "blue cloud" under nav_bar disappears, that's what I indicate above on the second screenshot.

Comment: thanks for your help. Maybe I have not expressed clearly my issue : there are the nav_bar menu which has the background "header_bg_min.jpg" and on the other hand, the "header_bg.jpg" background for horizontal_center container. I would like to have nav_bar fixed when I start scrolling and having "header_bg_min.jpg" not to disappear once this nav_bar is displayed.

Comment: look at  http://jsfiddle.net/71ndoe0p/1/ and more precisely when the nav_bar is going to appear, you can notice that header_bg_min.jpg is disappearing.

Comment: @user1773603 `when the nav_bar is going to appear, you can notice that header_bg_min.jpg is disappearing` it is not happening on my browser here. which browser/version you are testing on?