# Is it possible to start a WordPress shortcode with an HTML closing tag?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to create a custom WordPress shortcode to "break" into the page container I've created, so that I can display a *true* full width image in the natural flow of my page layout.  My issue is that WordPress doesn't seem to be respecting the fact that I'm starting my output with a closing HTML tag.

My page layout under normal circumstances uses a `.width-container` to provide a maximum width and some padding gutters.

```
<div class="width-container">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>

    <img src="" alt="">
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

What I would like to happen when using this shortcode is to first *close* the `.width-container` wrapper, insert some additional markup outside of a wrapper, then reopen a new `.width-container`, such as:

```
<div class="width-container">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>

<!-- shortcode -->
</div>

<div class="fullwidth-wrapper">
    <img src="" alt="">
</div>

<div class="width-container">
<!-- /shortcode -->

    <img src="" alt="">
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

I've attempted to use a closing and non-closing shortcode, I've tried using `ob_start()` / `ob_get_contents()` / `ob_end_clean()`, and seemingly every combination I can think of. I've tried `echo`ing, saving this as an HTML string to a var so I can return the output, and I've also tested this cross-browser to see if this was interference by the browser.  On each attempt, I get something like the following:

```
<div class="width-container">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>

<!-- shortcode -->
<div class="fullwidth-wrapper">
    <img src="" alt="">
</div>

    <div class="width-container"> <!-- this is now incorrectly double nested -->
<!-- /shortcode -->

        <img src="" alt="">
        <p>...</p>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This results in the double-nesting of `.width-container`, which is not the desired effect.

My `functions.php` shortcode:

```
/**
 * [fullwidth]
 * Custom shortcode to handle full-width images
 */
function full_width_image( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'src' => 'http://placehold.it/2000x900?text=Placeholder+Image',
        'alt' => 'Full Width Image Alt Text'
    ), $atts);

    ob_start();
    ?>
    </div>
    <div class="fullwidth-image-wrapper">
        <img class="fullwidth-image" src="<?php echo $a["src"]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $a["alt"]; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="width-container">
    <?php

    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'fullwidth', 'full_width_image' );
```

The [WordPress Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) hasn't been much help since after staring at the page for way too long I wasn't able to grok any particular mention of what I'm attempting, nor foregoing sanitation / processing of the HTML. **Is there a way to begin a shortcode with an HTML closing tag?**

Comment: Are there any filters used somewhere? Like `do_shortcode_tag`?

Comment: Not that I can see @inarilo, unless you've got a more specific example.

Comment: No, I just saw that the filter is applied in the `do_shortcode_tag` function which is used internally. What if you use `</div>` as the content parameter and return it at the beginning? hacky solution, if at all it works, but I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: Or better, instead of breaking, use css to make it full width.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm developing for not-super-technical team members, so a "hacky" solution won't cut it for me.  I _am_ using CSS to make this image full width, however if it's inside a `.width-container`, then the width...  ...will be...  ...contained.  So that won't work for me either.

Comment: You can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581034/is-there-are-way-to-make-a-child-divs-width-wider-than-the-parent-div-using-css

OR try this `<div></div></div>`, maybe it will fool whatever seems to be parsing this.

Comment: Unfortunately the first link won't work for me as I can't set this image to `position:absolute` without doing major hackery to not disturb the logical flow of the content which follows the image.

The leading open and close `div` does not work for me, either.

Comment: are you using any plugins that clean the html?

Answer (score 0):

The below code achieves what you're looking for.

Use: [fullwidth]Insert Image Tag Here[/fullwidth]

```
function full_width_image( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '</div> <div class="fullwidth-wrapper">' . $content . '</div> <div class="width-container">';
}
add_shortcode( 'fullwidth', 'full_width_image' );
```

The return initially returns a  to close the div previous, it then creates the new div to wrap the image. Following that it break to allow you to add your image as the content between the shortcode. It then closes the div and then opens a new one.

Your example shows that a variable is assigned with the image src and alt. However this option allows more flexibility as you can add any image in the space at any given time.