# Make child element go through beyond its parent width

Tags: html, css

I want to make child element to go beyond it's parent element. So further the parent element can apply `overflow-x: scroll`. Here some illustration on what I want to achieved, and what I got:

[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMnjI.jpg)

I have tried to solve the problem through applying `display: inline-block` to child element, or trying find out from similar question. but it hasn't solved my problem yet. Here is the html:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">Child Element</div>
   <div class="child">Child Element</div>
   <div class="child">Child Element</div>
   <div class="child">Child Element</div>
   <div class="child">Child Element</div>
</div>
```

Every child has a different width which if it added up will exceed parent width. Is there any solution or hint?

Comment: Provide your css too please

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581034/is-there-are-way-to-make-a-child-divs-width-wider-than-the-parent-div-using-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make a demo for you.

```css
.child1, .child3, .child4{
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child2, .child5{
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.parent{
  width: 1500px;
}

.scroll{
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="parent">
     <div class="child1">Child Element</div>
     <div class="child2">Child Element</div>
     <div class="child3">Child Element</div>
     <div class="child4">Child Element</div>
     <div class="child5">Child Element</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *accept and upvote my answer* is not an answer or explanation, it's simple noise that shouldn't be included within an answser. You should simply answer the question and focus on details related to the answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
.parent{
 max-width: 100%;
 overflow-x: scroll;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.child{
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">Child Element</div>
   <div class="child">Child Element</div>
   <div class="child">Child Element</div>
   <div class="child">Child Element</div>
   <div class="child">Child Element</div>
</div>
```