# Make a div wider than its parent without horizontal scrollbar and without overflow: hidden?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to get a child element to surpass the width of the parent element to the full extent of the browser without a horizontal scroll?

I've tried the solutions posted here [Is there are way to make a child DIV's width wider than the parent DIV using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581034/is-there-are-way-to-make-a-child-divs-width-wider-than-the-parent-div-using-css)

But with this particular HTML (see below) there's only one that works and yet creates an horizontal scrollbar (the extra width seen in the code snippet and the image below is causing the scrollbar to appear)

[image]

*I could always add an `overflow-x: hidden;` in `<body>` but I'd prefer not to

EDIT: There are certain css properties that even though do not make sense in the example, they should be kept in the solution (if any)

```html
    <div class="main">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="fit">
          something 1
        </div>
        <div class="parent">
          <header class="full full5">
            child full5
          </header>
        </div>
        <div class="fit">
          something 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```css
    body: {
      margin: 0px;
    }

    .main {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      background: #e8e8e8;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      margin: 0px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      max-width: 300px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .parent {
      display: flex;
      /* flex-direction: column; */
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #e9cccc;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
    }

    .fit {
      height: 50px;
    }

    .full {
      background-color: #d1ccd8a6;
      border: 1px solid #666;
      border-radius: 3px;
      height: 50px;
      padding: 0px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .full5 {
      width: 100vw;
      position: relative;
      left: 50%;
      right: 50%;
      margin-left: -50vw;
      margin-right: -50vw;
    }
```

```css
body: {
  margin: 0px;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: #e8e8e8;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: column; */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e9cccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.fit {
  height: 50px;
}

.full {
  background-color: #d1ccd8a6;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.full1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.full2 {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
}

.full3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 200%;
  left: -50%;
}

.full4 {
  margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  width: 100vw;
}

.full5 {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  margin-right: -50vw;
}

.full6 {
  margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  width: 100vw;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="fit">
      something 1
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <header class="full full1 hide">
        child full1
      </header>
      <header class="full full2 hide ">
        child full2
      </header>
      <header class="full full3 hide">
        child full3
      </header>
      <header class="full full4 hide">
        child full4
      </header>
      <header class="full full5">
        child full5
      </header>
      <header class="full full6 hide">
        child full6
      </header>
    </div>
    <div class="fit">
      something 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT2:**

If the `<body>` has a `margin:0` the posted solutions work, **except** if there is a vertical scrollbar (when isn't there one?)

Comment: Can you tell us which is parent and child ? and which element you need over which?

Comment: You can see the HTML for the hierarchie >> what I'd like is to have the "child full5" (as seen in the provided code snippet) to occupy the main div, but without going wider than that. The reason for the provided structure is because it resembles my current code

Comment: did you check my answer?

Comment: I don't understand a thing, *You want an element to be wider than it's parent without scrollbars*. the code you provided already answers the question ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak Actually, if there is a vertical scrollbar none of the solutions work

Answer (score 1):

Is this something you want?

I just made changes your CSS of `.main`, `.parent` and `.full-5`

```css
body: {
  margin: 0px;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: #e8e8e8;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: column; */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e9cccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
}

.fit {
  height: 50px;
}

.full {
  background-color: #d1ccd8a6;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.full1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.full2 {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
}

.full3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 200%;
  left: -50%;
}

.full4 {
  margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  width: 100vw;
}

.full5 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.full6 {
  margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  width: 100vw;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="fit">
      something 1
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <header class="full full1 hide">
        child full1
      </header>
      <header class="full full2 hide ">
        child full2
      </header>
      <header class="full full3 hide">
        child full3
      </header>
      <header class="full full4 hide">
        child full4
      </header>
      <header class="full full5">
        child full5
      </header>
      <header class="full full6 hide">
        child full6
      </header>
    </div>
    <div class="fit">
      something 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `position: sticky` is necessary (in the example it is useless, but it is not an error)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go(View it in full screen for visualization):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: #e8e8e8;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: column; */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e9cccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.fit {
  height: 50px;
}

.full {
  background-color: #d1ccd8a6;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.full1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.full2 {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
}

.full3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 200%;
  left: -50%;
}

.full4 {
  margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  width: 100vw;
}

.full5 {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  margin-right: -50vw;
}

.full6 {
  margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  width: 100vw;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="fit">
      something 1
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <header class="full full1 hide">
        child full1
      </header>
      <header class="full full2 hide ">
        child full2
      </header>
      <header class="full full3 hide">
        child full3
      </header>
      <header class="full full4 hide">
        child full4
      </header>
      <header class="full full5">
        child full5
      </header>
      <header class="full full6 hide">
        child full6
      </header>
    </div>
    <div class="fit">
      something 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I do see scrollbars in the snippet (?) It'd also be helpful if you could spot the changes in the code with some comments

Comment: I assume it is a browser scroll nothing to do with the code, I can try reducing some width if that helps.

Comment: @GWorking check the code, the scroll is fixed. `width` was not provided to the `container` hence there were scroll. Also I highlighted few places where I modified the code.

Comment: (you have eliminated the `max-width` of the `.container`, which is one of the requirements)

Comment: @GWorking had to leave for some work, Check the code now, hope it works for you now!

Comment: You've changed the `flex-direction: column` in main, so that elements are not centered. Getting it back destroys the layout here. Yet, a comment in the main question made me realize that the provided code already works (!) I'm thinking whether I delete the question or leave this opened for future users, thanks for your time nonetheless!!

Comment: LOL! yeah, so I have updated the code, it is up to you to keep the answer or take down!

Comment: sometimes we overlook things I guess.

Answer (score -1):

You can use z-index in css code to bring over than parent and fill color to push background

Comment: I've uploaded an image to better show what I'd like to correct, is the extra width of the child element