# Make child/nested layout not inherit parent layout

Tags: sveltekit

I want to render `child` route with child layout only, without inheriting root layout.

```
/routes/+layout.svelte
/routes/child/+layout.svelte
/routes/child/+page.svelte
```

I tried `child/+layout@.svelte` to break inheritance, but with no luck. I don't want to use layout groups or if-else statements in parent layouts.

Is there option to break parent inheritance in elegant way?

Comment: Layout groups were especially made for this, why don't you want to use tools provided ? This is like asking how to boil water without heating it.

Comment: @StephaneVanraes it's needed for just one page(or two) and I don't want to create a complicated structure to overcome such limitations. Thought that I overlooked something in this regards that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: @MaksimShamihulau Hii, did you find any good solution for this ? I am facing the same problem, and I could nt find any solution without using layout groups (so far).             and btw you can ask anything you want even "how to boil water without heating it ?" >> "reduce the pressure over the water and it will boil"

Answer (score 3):

As Stephane has mentioned in comment, you need **layouts group**. To quote the docs on breaking out of layouts:

> If you want some pages to have a different layout hierarchy than the rest, then you can **put your entire app inside one or more groups** except the routes that should not inherit the common layouts.

In example below home page `/` will use layout from `(app)` folder, but `/admin` will not inherit it.

```
src/routes/
│ (app)/
│ ├ dashboard/
│ ├ +page.svelte
│ └ +layout.svelte
├ admin/
└ +page.svelte
```

Read more here https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#advanced-layouts-group

Answer (score 1):

You can hide your root layout using stores:

Define store in:
`src/lib/stores/ui.ts`

```
import {writable} from "svelte/store";

export let showLayout = writable(true)
```

Add condition to layout in `src/routes/+layout.svelte`

```
<script lang="ts">
    import {showLayout} from "$lib/stores/ui";
</script>

{#if ($showLayout)}
    <div class="layout">
        <slot />
    </div>
{:else}
    <slot />
{/if}
```

Simply toggle layout off in your page
`src/routes/subpage/+page.svelte`

```
<script lang="ts">
    import {showLayout} from "$lib/stores/ui";

    $showLayout = false
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly doable with some CSS tricks. Refer to the following post for a good solution: [Is there a way to make a child DIV's width wider than the parent DIV using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581034/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-child-divs-width-wider-than-the-parent-div-using-css/24895631#24895631).

The simplest solution is to drop in a `+layout.svelte` file with the following contents:

```html
<main>
  <slot />
</main>

<style>
  main {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  }
</style>
```

This can be done with any container in the current context of the svelte component, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't break out of the root layout. You can do some CSS overriding, though I wouldn't call that "elegant."
Building off of acmiyaguchi's answer, I found that this worked better for me:

`+layout.svelte`

```
<main>
  <slot />
</main>

<style>
  main {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
  }
</style>
```